# Fitness watch that collects all heartrate and other data

Tags: wear-os, sony-smartwatch, fitbit

I'm looking for a watch or strap that collects data such as heartrate and GPS continuously. My goal is to then export this data for further analysis (analysis similar to what the Whoop does.)
I've considered a few things:

- WearOS devices. I'm sure I can write or download app that collects this kind of data (maybe Cardiogram), but I want to make sure it's as granular as possible. I'm worried that if I background the app, it won't have full access to data.
- Strap devices such as the Mi Fit. This seems to collect data 24/7 (and has long battery life), but I'm not sure what the granularity of the data is. I haven't found any sample data for download.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Within Fitbit dashboard, you will be able to get full access to all your own data. You may try it now by signing up an account and checking the following in your account:

[image]

The granularity of the data is minute by minute and you will only be able to access your own data. In order to collect a database of other participants for your research, you will have to either ask the participants to extract their own data and send a copy to you or develop an application or website to directly access their **Daily** data once they authorize you to do so (Minute by minute data from others is only available case by case and upon request).